How to replace first two fixed digits of a 4 digit number in Notepad++?
Let’s say I have these, and wish to replace 11 with 34 but only the first two digits of the 4 digits numbers:
defc 111 1211)
(def6t 1155
(defdt 1143
defa 113 1144)

To this:
defc 111 1211)
(def6t 3455
(defdt 3443
defa 113 3444)

How can this be done with find and replace with Notpad++?

I used find "11(\d{2})" replace with "34" but it result is this:
defc 111 1211)
(def6t 34
(defdt 34
defa 113 34)

perhaps (11)(\d{2}) replace with 34$2

thanks for help, unfortunate no luck

Is the first numbers always 11? or is it okay if it just always finds the first 2 numbers and make it 34 regardless? I'd go for something like this: find: (^.+?)\d{2} and replace with \134 (or find (^.+?)11 if its always 11).

yea the number is always fixed at 11.  the first one doesn't work it seems, but "(^.+?)11" will replace the leading first two digits that starts with 11 with 34, but it also remove the other text infront of the digits.  it also replaces digits such as 113 to 343 as well so can't seem to get it to work for just 4 digit length ones

I just reread the question. Will post the correct answer now.

You have to use word boundaries if you don't want to replace 12311567 with 12334567

Ctrl+H
Find what: \b11(?=\d\d\b)
Replace with: 34
TICK Wrap around
Search Mode Regular expression
Replace all

Explanation:
\b          # word boundary, avoid matching more digits before 11
11          # literally
(?=         # positive lookahead, make sure wwe have after:
    \d\d        # 2 digits
    \b          # word boundary, make sure we haven't digits after
)           # end lookahead

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):


amazing, this is even more to the tee to this example

From the first group that has 4 numbers, you want the first 2 of those numbers to be changed to 34.
Here's how you do that with Notepad++ and regular expressions.
Find: (^.+?)11(\d{2})
Replace with: \134\2
Lets explain.
We use (...) which means create capture groups and store their result in order of the group. \1 is for ^.+? and \2 is for \d{2}.
The search explained:
^ Search from the beginning of the line.
.+? Search for anything, non-greedy (so as soon as whatever comes after is found, it will put anything before that in the capture group.
11 Find exactly 11
(\d{2}) We find 2 digits and store them in a capture group. This is to ensure that a match with just 3 digits is not going to be changed. We really want a 4 digit match.
The replace explained:
\1 first capture group
34 our change
\2 second capture group

wow thanks for the detailed explanation man.  finally i understood what all the forward/backward slash meant.  I tried to upvote your solution but it says i require 15 reputation to do so.

That's okay. :) Glad I could help.
